# What are the rules for introducing new creatures with initiative in battle?

Tags: dnd-5e, initiative

I'm a new DM running Lost Mines of Phandelver with a group of new players. We are all comfortable with not sticking 100% to the rules as we try and feel out what it means to play D&D 5e and what's fun. This website has been a great resource for answering my questions as they crop up. Now I have one that I haven't been able to wrap my head around from searching the internet...

There are two scenarios in a dungeon crawl, both related to initiative, that I would like some advice with.

1) After a battle in a room (e.g. Cragmaw Castle in LMoP), are all initiative rolls and the turn order wiped clean? Or is it typical for the same battle turn order to be used for the subsequent non-combat activities (moving around, inspecting things, etc.)?

In an example where a monster is hidden in the room, and someone discovers it with a perception check. Would I then roll initiative for that hidden monster and insert them into the turn order? Or does everyone re-roll initiative for this new combat?

I think the root of my question here is how do I respect the fact that some action has occurred to introduce an enemy into the scene (e.g. a character pulling back a curtain and suddenly is face to face with a waiting hobgoblin) while also respecting the rules of initiative?

2) I have a player who roleplays a rather impetuous and foolhardy fellow. Against better judgement, he is often barging in to rooms without really doing any checks for what may be on the other side of the door. What sort of questions should I be asking him about this action? He wants to be able to say "I yank the door open and charge in, attacking the first enemy I see.", but this feels wrong to me - to give the character carte blanche to suddenly attack.

Thanks, and please let me know if I can improve how I ask these questions.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! Those both look like good questions to me, but we find it works better to have one question per post. You can "ask a new question" for one of these, and then [edit] this post to have only the other. Make sense?

Comment: This definitely needs to be split into two questions, as they are completely unrelated

Answer (score -2):

You have at least 6 Questions here
 - How long do Initiative rolls last after a battle? 
(It ends immediately)

---

- Are Non-combat actions tied to initiative? 
  (only use initiative for non-combat if your players can't organically take action sized turns)

---

- What the rules for inserting a new monster into initiative? 
  (Once a new monster is introduced:
  WITHOUT surprise roll initiative and introduce it into the order.

  WITH surprise, it acts immediately
  and lives at that point on the initiative tracker)

---

- what are the rules for inserting a new monster into a non-initiative setting? 
  (New monsters that are revealed on their own terms get a surprise round, and then role initiative, else roll initiative for all)

---

- CORE QUESTION: **How do I interject new characters to an encounter?** 
  (see above)

---

- What are the rules for multiple actions from a single character? 
  (Your player is taking too many actions. "I yank open the door
  (action) and charge in (move)" would be the extent of his action for
  that turn, and mechanically an unsound idea.

Attacking the first enemy he sees would be a held action that requires a trigger, e.g.: The goblins hold their action, declaring they will attack the first thing that yanks open the door and charges in.

Comment: This needs some major formatting for readability.  Also, in the future, when you can clearly identify at least 6 questions in a question... flag the question, don't answer it - the question will likely change greatly, causing your answer to become obsolete.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as a “surprise round” in D&D 5e.